# How to extract a specific table from an url via Python?

Tags: python, url, download

I am currently looking at the following Link:

https://www.ishares.com/de/privatanleger/de/produkte/251931/ishares-stoxx-europe-600-ucits-etf-de-fund

There is a table that displays all Positions of the ETF. My goal is to extract the table and save it to a xlsx file. I wrote a code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ishares.com/de/privatanleger/de/produkte/251931/ishares-stoxx-europe-600-ucits-etf-de-fund'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
df.to_excel('my data.xlsx')
```

However, when I try pd.read_html(html) it show me always that no tables could have been found on the website. Does somebody know how to identify and pull the desired table via Python?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the website uses cookies, so, when you use the default link, it redirects you to a first page that needs you to click in a button to accept cookies. And then you go to the right page.
I encountered the right URL, that goes straight to the main page that you are looking for, try this:

```
url = 'https://www.ishares.com/de/privatanleger/de/produkte/251931/ishares-stoxx-europe-600-ucits-etf-de-fund?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true'

html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
print(df_list)
```

Here is my Output:

```
[Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ex-Tag, Fälligkeitsdatum, Gesamtausschüttung]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ex-Tag, Fälligkeitsdatum, Gesamtausschüttung]
Index: [],             Unnamed: 0  2012  2013  2014  2015  ...  2017  2018  2019  2020  2021
0    Gesamtrendite (%)   177   210    74   108  ...   108  -110   276   -19   251
1  Vergleichsindex (%)   178   212    72    96  ...   106  -108   268   -20   249

[2 rows x 11 columns],                             Unnamed: 0  ...  Von 31.Mär.2021Bis 31.Mär.2022
0    Gesamtrendite (%) Per 31.Mär.2022  ...                             863
1  Vergleichsindex (%) Per 31.Mär.2022  ...                             849

[2 rows x 6 columns],             Unnamed: 0   1J   3J   5J  10J  Seit Auflage
0    Gesamtrendite (%)  197  894  538  940           651
1  Vergleichsindex (%)  178  879  522  920           636,             Unnamed: 0  Seit 1.1.  1M  3M  ...    3J    5J    10J  Seit Auflage
0    Gesamtrendite (%)       -736 -80 -43  ...  2929  2994  14548         21694
1  Vergleichsindex (%)       -755 -92 -65  ...  2874  2896  14119         20904

[2 rows x 10 columns], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Emittententicker, Name, Sektor, Anlageklasse, Marktwert, Gewichtung (%), Nominalwert, Nominale, ISIN, Kurs, Standort, Börse, Marktwährung]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Kategorie, Fonds]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Kategorie, Fonds]
Index: [],                        Börse Ticker  ... Common Code (EOC) iNAV ISIN
0                      Xetra   EXSA  ...        186 794 77         -
1  Bolsa Mexicana De Valores   EXSA  ...                 -         -
2             Borsa Italiana   EXSA  ...                 -         -
3         SIX Swiss Exchange   EXSA  ...                 -         -

[4 rows x 14 columns]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look at it! I see however that the table that I need has only 2 rows and 10 columns and seems to be empty. Would you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: can you show-me which is the table that you want to find?

Comment: I am looking for the table called POSITION on the website. There should be around 600 entries for the respective stocks. I can see in your output that the code detects the correct table, but all entries are empty. Do you have an idea why entries are empty in the python output?

Comment: Hey @LFRBX, I looked into the table you are talking about. 
If I'm not mistaken is the table in the section "POSITIONEN", with the following header:
Emittententicker, Name,  Sektor, Anlageklasse, Marktwert, Gewichtung (%) ,Nominalwert, Nominale, ISIN, Marktwährung.

Well, there are multiple reasons of why this table isn't coming in the HTML in a request, but I think that the main reason is because the Table is made using an API and it takes a while to load, that is why it's not coming in the request. because the HTML of the table is not completely loaded in an instant request.

Comment: And also there is a problem in the request method,  because the table is not completely loaded in the HTML, it has 62 pages and there is some JavaScript logic that rewrites the divs with new values when you pass throught the pages of the table.

Comment: My tip would be, to instead of using a request, use a BOT using Selenium, to open a chrome driver (which is an instance of google chrome that you can give commands based on the HTML,  just like a normal user) and you'd be capable of click buttons, access links of the website, pass throught the pages of the table and load one by one and get the rewrited values of the table.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for helping our community and anshwering for specific questions. A complete anshwer to this would be develop a complete algorithm to do this task, and I'm sorry but It would take too much of my time. You can try to develop the logic with Selenium and ask specific questions here on Stack Overflow when you get stuck. In case you can't develop that, send me an email: julioclopes32@gmail.com And we can discuss a solution.  
I'm gonna leave a starting sample on selenium in another anshwer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would use Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
#maximize the window size  
driver.maximize_window()  
#navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```